# Custom ORMLite Persister to Return Wrapper Objects

Tags: ormlite

I am writing an application which uses ORMLite to connect to a back-end database. Since the application will be run over VPN I am trying to minimize database calls.

In order to minimize database calls I have created a set of classes to wrap the values for each field. Each wrapper class stores the original value returned from the database and also a current value. This allows things like reverting to the original value, or checking whether the value is dirty (ie. only update the database if one or more fields are dirty).

The implication of this regarding ORMLite is that ORMLite never returns a `null` value when it queries the database (even if the database returns `null`). If there is a `null` value in the database it returns a fully initialized "wrapper" with the `currentValue` and `originalValue` variables set to null.

It seems that the right place to do this is in a custom persister such as (where `StatefulIntegerProperty` is the wrapper for the `Integer`):

```
public class StatefulIntegerPersister extends BaseDataType {

    ... misc. other code

    @Override
    public Object resultToSqlArg(FieldType fieldType, DatabaseResults results, int columnPos) throws SQLException {
        Integer result = results.getInt(columnPos);
        return new StatefulIntegerProperty((results.wasNull(columnPos)) ? null : result);
    }

    @Override
    public Object sqlArgToJava(FieldType fieldType, Object sqlArg, int columnPos) throws SQLException {
        return sqlArg;
    }

    @Override
    public Object javaToSqlArg(FieldType fieldType, Object obj) throws SQLException {
        return ((StatefulIntegerProperty)obj).getCurrentValue();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStreamType() {
        return true; // this is a hack to work around ORMLite setting the value to null in the FieldType.resultToJava function
    }
}
```

I have three questions:

1. Is this the correct approach?
2. In the ORMLite `FieldType.resultToJava` function it seems to do a null check and will replace my wrapper with `null` if the database returned null. Right now I am getting past this by overriding the `isStreamType` method in the persister to return true. Is this the best approach, and will I find later an unintended negative side effect?
3. What is the difference between the `resultToSqlArg` and `sqlArgToJava` methods in a custom persister, and specifically, which one of these should I use to wrap the value returned from the DB, and then what should I be doing in the other?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the correct approach?

I don't understand why anything that you are doing here minimizes database calls.  Can you start a discussion on the [users' mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ormlite-user)?

Right now you are overriding the `resultToSqlArg(...)` method when I think you want the `sqlArgToJava(...)`.  See below.

> Right now I am getting past this by overriding the isStreamType method in the persister to return true. Is this the best approach...

Hrm.  If it works then fine but it seems dangerous to use this setting in this manner.  If I changed the behavior of the `isStreamType()` method then this may break your code.  At the very least you should have unit tests to confirm this behavior that will break if you upgrade ORMLite.

That said, there is good handling in the code specifically around `null` values if `isStreamType()` is true.

> What is the difference between the resultToSqlArg and sqlArgToJava...

I've fleshed out the javadocs for these.

- `resultToSqlArg` takes the object from the SQL results and turns it into a java-object suitable to be an argument to SQL commands.  For example, if you have a date-long type, this will extract a `Long` value from the database results.
- `sqlArgToJava` takes the sql-arg value and converts it into our Java field.  For example, if you have a date-long type, this will take a `Long` value and convert it into a `Date` which matches the entity field.

I think you should override the `sqlArgToJava` and *not* the `resultToSqlArg`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My logic is that storing the values retrieved from the database mean that I won't have to query the database to check if the record is dirty, and if the record is not dirty I won't have to send an update to the database. Also, if the user wants to revert their changes I won't have to query the database to get the original values. I did post this to the mailing list for further discussion.

Comment: The problem with overriding the sqlArgToJava function seems to be that if the resultToSqlArg returns a null value the BaseFieldConverter.resultToJava method will return a null and never call the sqlArgToJava method.